# Can only parse the first page of a website

Tags: python, parsing

```
x = 0
htmlpar= ""
dictlist = []
datalist = [223, 236, 250, 263, 277, 290, 304, 317, 331, 344, 358, 371, 385, 398, 412, 425, 439, 452, 466, 479]
from urllib.request import urlopen
from html.parser import HTMLParser
html = urlopen("http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&appid=730#p5_quantity_desc").read().decode('utf-8')
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_data(self, data):
        global x
        global datalist
        global dictlist
        x += 1
        if x in datalist:
            dictlist.append(data)
MyHTMLParser().feed(html)
print(dictlist)
input()
```

Outputs:

```
['0.03', 'Sticker Capsule',  
 '0.03', 'Sticker Capsule 2', 
 '0.04', 'eSports Winter Case',  
 '0.04', 'CS:GO Weapon Case 3', 
 '0.11', 'Winter Offensive Weapon Case', 
 '0.04', 'Community Sticker Capsule 1', 
 '0.10', 'CS:GO Weapon Case 2', 
 '0.39', 'Operation Phoenix Weapon Case', 
 '1.10', 'Huntsman Weapon Case', 
 '0.72', 'eSports Case']
```

When I try to parse any page it keeps doing only the first page on the steam market: http://steamcommunity.com/market/search?q=&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any&appid=730#p5_quantity_desc

The url clearly has "#p5" (page 5), but the top thing for page five is a 5-7, while it keeps printing the sticker capsule (top of first).

I feel this might only be with steam because on the website if you change pages it only reloads the box with the data in it and not the whole web page, but I want to make sure something silly is not in my code.

Comment: Sounds like there is some javascript that isn't being executed, not sure if urllib can handle that

Comment: would there be a way to get the javascript?

Comment: I hit page6 url --> http://steamcommunity.com/market/search/render/?query=&start=50&count=10&search_descriptions=0&sort_column=quantity&sort_dir=desc&appid=730&category_730_ItemSet%5B%5D=any&category_730_Weapon%5B%5D=any  and got json like --> {  "success": true,  "start": 60,  "pagesize": 10,  "total_count": 2676,  "results_html": "your stuff"} . Parse results_html from html parser